# Did I fill out this F1-Score Interpretation Matrix correctly?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification

My goal is to make a matrix in order to help me better understand the F1-Score and interpred it correctly in a classification problem. Following my research I came up with this Matrix, but had trouble to fill it out. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to come up with a generizable interpretation of the F1 score which can be applied to different analytical tasks (Regression, Classification, ...)?
2. Did I chose the correct structure for the matrix (Binary/Multiclass and Balanced/Unbalanced) or did I miss something important?
3. If yes, are the fields I filled out so far correct, and how to fill out the rest?

[image]